# how to close iframe popup in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my parent page, from where i'm opening a popup

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Popup example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenPop() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var layer = document.createElement("div");
            layer.style.zIndex = 2;
            layer.id = "layer";
            layer.style.position = "absolute";
            layer.style.top = "0px";
            layer.style.left = "0px";
            layer.style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";
            layer.style.width = width + "px";
            layer.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            layer.style.opacity = "0.75";
            layer.style.filter += ("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=75)");
            document.body.style.position = "static";
            document.body.appendChild(layer);
            var size = { "height": 220, "width": 400 };
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            var popUrl = 'popup.htm';
            iframe.name = "Logic Form";
            iframe.id = "popup";
            iframe.src = popUrl;
            iframe.style.height = size.height + "px";
            iframe.style.width = size.width + "px";
            iframe.style.position = "fixed";
            iframe.style.zIndex = 3;
            iframe.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            iframe.frameborder = "0";
            iframe.style.top = ((height + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / 2) - (size.height / 2) + "px";
            iframe.style.left = (width / 2) - (size.width / 2) + "px";
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a onclick="OpenPop();" href="#">OpenPopup</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this is my popup.html page,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeIframe() {
            var iframe = opener.document.getElementById("popup");
            var layer = opener.document.getElementById("layer");
            iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
            layer.parentNode.removeChild(layer);
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h3>This is Popup</h3>
        <a onclick="closeIframe();" href="#">Close</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

problem : on popup.html , there is close button, who is calling function to remove iframe, but i am not able to close popup, anybody help?

**OR**  anybody have better solution or example to do popup like this?

any help highly appreciated

Comment: does your control goes to function closeIframe() function when you click on Close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CloseIframe` method should be:

```
function closeIframe() {
    window.parent.ClosePop();
}
```

and in your main page, right under `OpenPop` method, add the close action, like:

```
function ClosePop() {
    var layer = document.getElementById("layer");
    var iframe = document.getElementById("popup");
    document.body.removeChild(layer); // remove layer
    document.body.removeChild(iframe); // remove div
}
```

Comment: working in Fine, but the result of pop is not same in firefox and google chorme

Comment: you will get error in Chrome for the browser policy, just open the console and see that the error is because you're using a local file. The example works in any browser, even IE ;)
- `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL` it's a policy error, not code error in your example, unless the pop up is in other domain, and that will throw a CROSS-DOMAIN exception.

Comment: result of this code in different browser :- 

[1]FF : -  http://postimage.org/image/o1o620bdz/

[2] IE :-  http://postimage.org/image/3qli76xt3/

[3] Google Chrome :- http://postimage.org/image/iwhwguihb/

Comment: That is **your CSS** - *your question is about Javascript and how to close the iFrame* - I would always use a CSS Framework when developing cross browser pages, like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html). What I was mentioning was the javascript part to close the iframe, that works in every browser.

Comment: ok, i agree, but do i need to open new question for this? i need something that works good in all browser

Comment: @Vir_ you shoudl accept the answer if it answers your question, regarding the rest, I have told you what you could do for cross-browser, just use a CSS Framework, like Bootstrap f.ex. - Here is a simple example for it: http://jsbin.com/edawac/1/ (Note that I'm not using any javascript whatsoever, just making use of the [Modal component of Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)).

Comment: but it's possible to load popup.html in iframe using this? i just want to use iframe!

Comment: I have presented you some solutions, please do as you like, read the documentation so you know what's going on on the Modal. Take yourself one step further and do more reasearch on the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) box for showing modal popup window. It will be easy to handle.

Also there are lots of jQuery plugins available for showing popup like [fancy box](http://fancybox.net/), [color box](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), etc

Comment: i'm looking for to do with iframe only !